# When can any graph $G$ be expressed as a union of $\alpha(G)$ complete graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, packing-and-covering

If for any graph $H$ we define $\alpha(H)$ to be the cardinality of any maximum size indepedent set in $H$. Then under what conditions can any graph $G$ be expressed as a union of $\alpha(G)$ complete graphs?

Or equivalently if $[S]_2$ is the set of all two element subsets of $S$, then for which class of graphs $G$ will there exist $\alpha(G)$ sets $V_{1},V_2,\ldots V_{\alpha(G)}$ that satisfy $V(G)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\alpha(G)}V_n$ and $E(G)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\alpha(G)}[V_n]_2$?

Are there any reasonably simple necessary and sufficient conditions for categorizing these graphs?

---

---

Lastly also note if there are $n$ complete graphs $C_1,C_2,\ldots C_n$ with $G=\bigcup_{k=1}^n C_k$ and $n<\alpha(G)$ there must exist an independent set $I$ of $G$ such that $|I|=n+1$ however by assumption we have that $I\subseteq V(G)=\bigcup_{k=1}^nV(C_k)$ therefore by the pigeonhole principal there must exists two distinct vertices $u,v\in V(C_j)$ for some integer $1\leq j\leq n$ yet since $V(C_j)$ is a clique of $G$ this means we have $\{u,v\}\in E(G)$ contradicting the fact $I$ is an independent set of $G$, which proves $n\geq \alpha(G)$. Thus a a corollary if we let $\theta(G)$ be the [intersection number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_number_(graph_theory)) of $G$ then by definition we have that:

$$G\text{ is a union of }\alpha(G)\text{ complete graphs}\iff \alpha(G)=\theta(G)$$

However I'm unable to simplify these equivalent conditions into anything nice either.

Comment: Do you have an example showing it's a proper subclass of this class? What is the context in which this question is asked?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda  I don't understand your trees example. $\alpha(G)$ can be as small as $n/2$ but $n-1$ cliques are needed to cover the edges.

Comment: What does "$G$ is a union of complete graphs" mean? I would have thought that every (simple) graph is a union of complete graphs. What is an example of a graph which is not a union of complete graphs?

Comment: @bof I made a slight error and was referring to complete graphs on three or more vertices I reverted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a pretty answer to this question.  A graph is in this class iff it is the union of a set of cliques such that each of the cliques has a vertex not in any of the other cliques.

Given a maximum independent set $S$, you can identify said cliques as the closed neighbourhoods of the vertices in $S$. Conversely given such a set of cliques, the special vertices are a maximum independent set.

Answer (score 1):

I know I already accepted an answer nine months ago, though these came up again in a problem I was working on involving digraph Kernels and upon further investigation these are actually called "[bound graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_graph)" as a matter of fact we have the following chain of equivalences:
$$G\text{ is a bound graph}\iff\alpha(G)=\theta(G)\iff \vartheta(G)=\theta(G)\\\iff\text{For all spanning subgraphs }H\text{ of }G\text{ we have }\theta(H)\geq\theta(G)\\\iff \text{For all subgraphs }H\text{ of }G\text{ we have }\theta(H)\geq \theta(G[V(H)])$$

Thus the property of being a "bound graph" is hereditary which means for any bound graph $G$ we see every induced subset $H$ of $G$ is a bound graph and therefore note for every induced subset $H$ of $G$ we have the identity $\alpha(H)=\theta(H)=\vartheta(H)$ though this means every induced subgraph $H$ of $G^{\complement}$ satisfies $\chi(H)=\omega(H)$ thus $G^{\complement}$ must be a perfect graph which by the [Perfect graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph_theorem) this means $G$ is a perfect graph. Thus this proves bound graphs are a particular class of perfect graphs.